# How can I use Flask on Python, Spyder via Anaconda?

Tags: python

It looks like I can't run Python using Flask.

My file is "hello.py" and this is the code:

```
from flask import Flask

myapp = Flask(__name__)

@myapp.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hello!'
```

It runs fine, but if I do `set FLASK_APP=hello.py`
it gives me,

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Then if I do: `env:FLASK_APP=hello.py` again, it runs, but then do the `export FLASK_APP=hello.py` gives me the same syntax error.

Comment: Are you using Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
from flask import Flask
myapp = Flask(__name__)

@myapp.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hello!'
# Add this line
myapp.run()
```

and running the Python file as `python hello.py`.

Comment: thanks.  it just worked.  i guess "myapp.run" was all i needed.

Comment: Accept it as answer, if this answer has solved your problem

Comment: i did it. i am still new to this platform, and didn't know.

Comment: *What* happened after (it appears incomplete)? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63841550/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if was written today).

Answer (score 0):

These are commands, assuming you are in a directory with file `hello.py`.

```sh
# Unix Bash (Linux, Mac, Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL))
export FLASK_APP=hello
flask run

# Windows CMD:
set FLASK_APP=hello
 flask run

# Windows PowerShell:
env:FLASK_APP = "hello"
flask run
```

Tested with `hello.py` in Windows and WSL Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa):

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

Comment: my python environment doesn't like "set FLASK_APP" for some reason.
right now, it started working again, thx for your tip.

Comment: What environment is that?

Comment: i use spyder via anaconda navigator 3.